# Two matrices $A, B$ satisfying in characteristic polynomial of $B$ and $A$, respectively.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, characteristic-functions

Let matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A$ satisfy in characteristic polynomial of $B$, and $B$ satisfy in characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Can we say that:

$A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $B$ be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true for the characteristic polynomial. For example take the zero matrix of order 2 ,and take the 2×2 matrix with zero's everywhere except the top right corner.
They have the same characteristic polynomial X^2 and therefore the condition holds, but the first is diagonizable and the second isnt.

Comment: It is interesting to notice that if we replace the characteristic polynomial by the minimal polynomial, then it works. In particular the minimal polynomal is able to distinguish these two matrices because its degree is more flexible.